# Getting Json-Data from Fetch

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

my Json-file is a simple Object with 2 arrays:

```
{ 
"key1": ["a", "b", "c"],
"key2": [ "d", "e", "f"] 
}
```

in Javascript I'm using fetch to get the data.
To use the data I'm pushing it into an array

```
const jsonData = '/things.json';
const myArray = [];

fetch(jsonData)
.then(answer => answer.json())
.then(data => myArray.push(data))

console.log(myArray); //this gives me a nested array

console.log(myArray[0]); //undefined
```

putting myArray through a loop also gives me an //undefined

using the spread syntax or concat gives me //Found non-callable @@iterator

How can I get the content of that array?

Comment: your `console.log`s are occuring before your `.then`. Move them inside of the function being passed to .then and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @Gavin , Your `console.log` statement should execute after `fetch` has completed. One of the ways to do that would be to add that in another `then`.

```js
fetch(jsonData)
.then(answer => answer.json())
.then(data => myArray.push(data))
.then(() => console.log(myArray[0]));
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is this:

```
const jsonData = '/things.json';
const myArray = [];

fetch(jsonData)
.then(answer => answer.json())
.then(data => myArray.push(...data)) //Notice the spread operator
```

**UPDATE**
Seems like spread operator is not working in your project you can do this too:

```
const jsonData = '/things.json';
const myArray = [];

fetch(jsonData)
.then(answer => answer.json())
.then(data => myArray = data);
```

For `...` not to work on your projects, there could be various solutions, one of them being changing `target` in `tsconfig` to `"target": "es5"`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The spreadsyntax gives me: Found non-callable @@iterator

Comment: @strangePotatoe basically just to avoid nesting, what I was doing was this:
`var a = [1, 2, 9, 5, 7];` `myArray.push(...a)` so `myArray` will now be  `[1, 2, 9, 5, 7]`; This should work. The reason why it's not working is your project might not be supporting `...` spread operators. See the updated answer then.

Answer (score 0):

After you receive the JSON data 
Simply use 
`const array=Object.values(jsonData)`

I meant

```
fetch(location).then((response)=>{
response.json().then((data)=>{
const array=Object.values(data)
```